# LUIS: args.dialog is undefined

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, azure-language-understanding

when I fire query from LUIS web app I am getting this json response:

````
```
{
  "query": "I am piyush ",
  "topScoringIntent": {
    "intent": "askDetails",
    "score": 0.9953322,
    "actions": [
      {
        "triggered": false,
        "name": "askDetails",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "firstName",
            "type": "User Name::First Name",
            "required": true,
            "value": [
              {
                "entity": "piyush",
                "type": "User Name::First Name",
                "resolution": {}
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "lastName",
            "type": "User Name::Last Name",
            "required": true,
            "value": null
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "intents": [
    {
      "intent": "askDetails",
      "score": 0.9953322,
      "actions": [
        {
          "triggered": false,
          "name": "askDetails",
          "parameters": [
            {
              "name": "firstName",
              "type": "User Name::First Name",
              "required": true,
              "value": [
                {
                  "entity": "piyush",
                  "type": "User Name::First Name",
                  "resolution": {}
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "lastName",
              "type": "User Name::Last Name",
              "required": true,
              "value": null
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "intent": "None",
      "score": 0.0756940544
    }
  ],
  "entities": [
    {
      "entity": "piyush",
      "type": "User Name::First Name",
      "startIndex": 5,
      "endIndex": 10,
      "score": 0.9813254,
      "resolution": {}
    }
  ],
  "dialog": {
    "prompt": "Please enter your Last Name",
    "parameterName": "lastName",
    "parameterType": "User Name::Last Name",
    "contextId": "52a81547-9896-4d80-ad58-85606b51cb89",
    "status": "Question"
  }
}
```
````

when I run same url from node js code I am not getting same response as shown above:

````
```
var builder = require("botbuilder");
var recognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer(LuisModelUrl);
var intents = new builder.IntentDialog({ recognizers: [recognizer] });
intents.matches('askDetails', [
        function(session, args, next) {
            console.log('dialog', args.dialog);
       }
]);
````

```

args.dialog is undefined over here, it is not giving me same json in args variable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use args.dialog. Take a look to the [Luis sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/intelligence-LUIS) to get an idea of how code should be in `Node.js`.

If you are looking to print Luis response, try using `args.Entities`.

Comment: thanks for reply, but my issue is that, when user input something then for incomplete  information I want to display dialog to user based on json response, that's why I want dialog.

Comment: As I said, take a look the sample I provided. There you will find how to do it.

Comment: I want dialog which LUIS returning in json response to show to user that which information is remaining.

Comment: All right, now it's a bit more clear what you are looking for. Try adding a "&verbose=true" at the end of luis v2 endpoint (the value you have in the LuisModelUrl variable). Let me know if that works and I will update the answer

Comment: Thanks for your concern but still I am not getting dialogs in NodeJS code, I want to them in my NodeJS code.